# Increasing the count every time a function runs

Tags: python

I just started to learn Python. I am going through a book and making a text based game.

So I have a room. I want to make the player die if he/she comes into the room 3 times but couldn't figure out how to do.

```
def spawn():
    count = 0
    count += 1
    print(count)
    print("You dropped down nearly to the magma.")
    print("There are four doors around you.")
    print("Which one do you take?")
    ch = input("Top, bottom, left or right? > ")
    if count = 4:
        dead("You wandered around too much and died.")
    else:
        print()
```

I tried to track the number with printing but I can't make it increase. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: When I put count outside the function it gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex.py", line 147, in <module>
    spawn()
  File "ex.py", line 14, in spawn
    count += 1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'count' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well in the function you each time set a *local* variable to `0`, so that means that *after* the function is done, that variable no longer exists.

The trick is to use a variable that remains "active" after the function exists. For example a variable outside the function, or you can add an *attribute* to the function that you increment. The advantage of the latter is that it is more clear that this is something related to the function, like:

```
def spawn():
    spawn.count += 1
    print(spawn.count)
    print("You dropped down nearly to the magma.")
    print("There are four doors around you.")
    print("Which one do you take?")
    ch = input("Top, bottom, left or right? > ")
    if spawn.count == 4:
        dead("You wandered around too much and died.")
    else:
        print()

spawn.count = 0
```

Note that you also forgot to use double equal signs (`==`) for the `if` statement (equality check versus assignment).

Comment: neat trick to html code/b this yourself. why is there no `global` needed? `spawn` a class-instance not shown? or does this add the variable to the `spawn`-function itself? never seen that trick so far.

Comment: @PatrickArtner: no `spawn` is the name of the function :) Just like classes, objects, etc. functions can have attributes. If you write a "standalone" function, then it is better to "encapsulate" its state (well it is not very common, and probably not elegant design that a function has a state, but that's another discussion), and not expose it (directly) to the outside world.

Comment: Thats a gem:) thanks for providing - you just need to "init" the attribute outside first from what my testing showed.

Comment: @PatrickArtner That's a function attribute, an attribute of the function object itself. Every function already has some, like `.__doc__` for the docstring, and `.__name__`, but you can add others if you want, although some people don't like that.

Comment: alright its good that you learned it to me. working perfect now, thank you :)

Comment: @PatrickArtner: yes, well you can "init" it in the function as well, but this would mean that each time we call the function we would "init" it. Yes, we can check if the function has an attribute, and if not init it, but that would make it less elegant, and a bit less efficient.

Comment: Wow, I never saw this before. This is brilliant and very pythonic in the way that "everything is an object".

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do it like this:

```
def spawn():
    if not hasattr(spawn, 'count'):
        spawn.count = 0
    spawn.count += 1
    print(spawn.count)
    print("You dropped down nearly to the magma.")
    print("There are four doors around you.")
    print("Which one do you take?")
    ch = input("Top, bottom, left or right? > ")
    if spawn.count == 4:
        dead("You wandered around too much and died.")
    else:
        print()
```